# How can I set one array as a value of another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, list

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => James
    [1] => Mike
    [2] => Liam
    [3] => Shantel
    [4] => Harry
)
Array
(
    [0] => Green
    [1] => Blue
    [2] => Yellow
    [3] => Purple
    [4] => Red
)
```

How can I get these two arrays into a JSON object?

So this should be the expected output:

```
{"James":"Green","Mike":"Blue","Liam":"Yellow","Shantel":"Purple"}
```

This is what I tried doing but I'm getting a totally different output:

```
$final = array();
$names = ['James', 'Mike', 'Liam', 'Shantel', 'Harry']
$colors = ['Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Red']


for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $final[] = array_push($final, $names[$i], $colors[$i]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set a specific key of `$final` to a specific value. So instead of using `array_push` (or `$final[]`), which just adds a value to an indexed array, you want to define the key/value of the associated array `$final` like:

```
$final[$names[$i]] = $colors[$i];
```

```
$final = array();
$names = ['James', 'Mike', 'Liam', 'Shantel', 'Harry'];
$colors = ['Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Red'];


foreach($names as $i => $key) {
    $final[$key] = $colors[$i];
}
```

Working example at https://3v4l.org/cgHtD

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Answer (score 2):

Try `array_combine()`

```
$a = ["James", "Mike", "Liam", "Shantel", "Harry"];

$b = ["Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Purple", "Red"];

$c = array_combine($a, $b);


print_r($c);

echo json_encode($c);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [James] => Green
    [Mike] => Blue
    [Liam] => Yellow
    [Shantel] => Purple
    [Harry] => Red
)
{"James":"Green","Mike":"Blue","Liam":"Yellow","Shantel":"Purple","Harry":"Red"}
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)